# Forcing INNER JOIN / LEFT JOIN precedence and groups

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, mariadb

I'm having a bunch of tables let's say A, B1, B2, C1, C2.

I'm selecting from A, joining on B1, itself joining on B2. I'm also selecting from A on C1, itself joining on C2, I mean:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM A
     JOIN B1 ON A.b1 = B1.id
     JOIN B2 ON B1.b2 = B2.id
LEFT JOIN C1 ON A.c1 = C1.id
LEFT JOIN C2 ON C1.c2 = C2.id
```

I want the whole query to fail if the B branch fail, which is cleanly done which those JOINs.

But I also want the branch of "C"s to fail if `LEFT JOIN C2` fails (I don't want the informations from C1 in this case, I want NULLS), but I still want the whole query to succeed if C branch fails.

So I need a kind of:

```
    SELECT *
      FROM A
      JOIN B1 ON A.b1 = B1.id
      JOIN B2 ON B1.b2 = B2.id
 LEFT JOIN (C1 ON A.c1 = C1.id
       JOIN C2 ON C1.c2 = C2.id)
```

But it's not an existing syntax as far as I know.

So I'm currently implementing it either as:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM A
     JOIN B1 ON A.b1 = B1.id
     JOIN B2 ON B1.b2 = B2.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
             FROM C1
             JOIN C2 ON C1.c2 = C2.id) AS C ON A.c1 = C.c1
```

Either with views.

Which works like a charm, allowing me to explicitly express which JOIN goes with which JOIN, and their precedences, but it's heavy to write and heavy to read, also a bit redundent.

But is there another clean solution I missed?

Test set:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A;
CREATE TABLE A (b1 int, c1 int);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B1;
CREATE TABLE B1 (id int, b2 int);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B2;
CREATE TABLE B2 (id int);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS C1;
CREATE TABLE C1 (id int, c2 int);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS C2;
CREATE TABLE C2 (id int);

INSERT INTO C2 VALUES (1), (2), (3); -- To remove to make join fail.
INSERT INTO C1 VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3);

INSERT INTO B2 VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO B1 VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3);

INSERT INTO A VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3);
```

Comment: Yes, you can use parentheses with joins to force a certain order of the joins

Comment: @Shadow It syntax errors on MariaDB 10, have you tested it on another implementation?

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct syntax for parenthesized joins:

```
SELECT *
  FROM A
  JOIN B1 ON A.b1 = B1.id
  JOIN B2 ON C1.b2 = B2.id
  LEFT JOIN 
   (C1 JOIN C2 ON C1.c2 = C2.id)
  ON A.c1 = C1.id
```

Think of how you would use parentheses in familiar arithmetic syntax. You wouldn't write:

```
A * B1 * B2 (* C1 * C2)
```

You would write:

```
A * B1 * B2 * (C1 * C2)
```

That is, the multiplication operator is a binary operator, so it has two operands, a left and a right. An operand can be a term or a parenthesized sub-expression. But the sub-expression must follow the same rules, where multiplication is still a binary operator. You don't get to stick a binary operator off to the left end of the expression.

Comment: This ones syntax errors on MariaDB server 10.0.29, and I found no documentation about it. Error is "near 'ON A.c1 = C1.id'".

Comment: Move the `ON A.c1 = C1.id` join condition after the parentheses because `A` is defined outside: `(C1 JOIN C2 ON C1.c2 = C2.id) ON A.c1 = C1.id

Comment: Thanks, that's correct, I've fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

My current solution is to create a view like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VC AS
SELECT C1.id AS c1_id, C2.id AS c2_id
  FROM C1
  JOIN C2 ON C1.c2 = C2.id;
```

And simply LEFT JOINing on it:

```
SELECT *
  FROM A
  JOIN B1 ON A.b1 = B1.id
  JOIN B2 ON B1.b2 = B2.id
  LEFT JOIN VC ON VC.c1_id = A.c1;
```

It keeps the solution readable, and the view is reusable in other queries which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know

```
SELECT *
  FROM A
  INNER JOIN (B1,B2) 
     ON  A.b1 = B1.id
     AND C1.b2 = B2.id
  LEFT JOIN (C1,C2) 
     ON  A.c1 = C1.id
     AND C1.c2 = C2.id)
```

would work as expected

```
SELECT ... FROM (t1,t2) WHERE ... is the same as t1 INNER JOIN t2
```

the example above works "like" INNER JOIN, in Facts as i know it is CROSS JOIN, thats slightly different ... but until now i didNt understood what the real difference is, maybe someone can tell us ;)

until then, the example obove should work for you

Comment: Mixing the comma syntax with explicit joins is not really a great idea

Comment: please explain your Statement, what are the reasons for not doing so?

Comment: Comma-style join syntax is from SQL-89 and it is supported only as legacy syntax. There's nothing *wrong* with it, but in certain cases of mixing legacy syntax with SQL-92 `JOIN` syntax can cause confusion. For example `FROM A, B JOIN C ON B.x=C.y AND C.z = A.z` throws an error because the `JOIN` is evaluated before the comma, therefore as the join condition is evaluated, it doesn't know that table A is even referenced in the query. It's possible to work around, but it's confusing for some developers, so it's best to avoid mixing the syntaxes.

Comment: ok thanks, maybe it never showed up for me because i always use brackets